# ¿Cómo puedo evitar exportar un botón con el exportador de data tables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

tengo este problema,
En las data table tengo mis columnas ejemplo

Nombre   apeliido    eliminar
prueba     prueba    (Aqui pongo mi boton para eliminar)

Cuando exporto a excel mi tercera columna me aparece asi `<button id="123" class="">eliminar </button>`

Cuando yo quisiera que me apareciera solo el nombre de mi botón (eliminar) no quiero que me exporte toda la declaración.

Espero me haya explicado

Comment: Sería ideal que mostraras cómo estás  llevando los datos de la consulta a tu datatable para ayudarte mejor pero el api tiene la opción de seleccionar qué columnas exportar. Lo que buscas se hace con: exportOptions: {columns: [1,2,3,] } (donde 1,2,3 son las columnas que deseas exportar  )

Comment: @EduardoMunizaga, si entiendo que hay esa opción el detalle es que por ejemplo en mi api viene una columna que es opción si el dato de la columna opcion es no realizado, me pone un boton rojo de no realizado y al revez si el dato viene como realizada me pone un boton en verde que dice realizada,, yo quisiera tambien exportar eso para saber cuantas realizadas y cuantas no desde excel pero al exportar me sale el '<button....' cuando solo quisiera que me pusiera realizada o no realizada